# Async queue in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I'm building an app to generate catalogs. Data I need to load are often more than 50mb so to do not disrupt user experience I tried to use a queue in Laravel.

I have a job class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use PDF;
use App\Jobs\ProcessCatalog;

class ProcessCatalog implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $id;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id=$id;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
             //code which generate catalogs
    }
}
```

I tried to run this with:

```
public function generateC() {

    ProcessCatalog::dispatch(1);

return 'it works'; 
}
```

and everything works fine when the queue is sync but when I QUEUE_DRIVER=sync to QUEUE_DRIVER=database
everything seems that work but catalog never generated...

I need to run queue async? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: did you [install database table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#driver-prerequisites)?

Comment: yes, I install database table of course... when I run with artisan work well but when I try to run from controller doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To Laravel database queue driver, you must first migrate the queue table:

```
php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate
```

And you must then run the queue worker:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

Comment: I migrate the tables but I want to run queue from Controller, not from artisan... when I run from artisan works well...

Comment: @AleksPer Then use the 'sync' driver but it completely defeats the point of using queues. Controllers only run when there's a request, it's synchronous. Queues are used to run tasks asynchronously, when there's no requests. To accomplish this, you need a process to  run in the background and watch for jobs in the queue.

Comment: I'm creating catalogs and I need to create only when the user requests it. Because of UX I don't want to block a user from other actions so I need to generate catalogs in the background using queue... I'm thinking now might be better to use CRON

Comment: @AleksPer CRON is for scheduled tasks. I think queues are perfect for what you want to do. I know it can be annoying to run and monitor a queue worker but it's the best way to do it IMO. All the best.

Comment: Thanks I found https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-async-queue